# How do I build a series of pyqt5 buttons using tuples from a mysql database?

Tags: python, pyqt5, mysql-python

I am currently building a POS system using PyQt and storing which products are currently available from a mysql database.  I would like to build a group box filled with buttons that each have the name and price of a particular product.  That way, the user can push said button to add the current product to their transaction list.  However, I do not know how the database connector sends the tuples back to my script.

Unfortunately, I was not able to try very much, as I have hit this problem while developing the backend of our system.

Comment: You should consider [Qt model/view system](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html) with a model like [QSqlQueryModel](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqlquerymodel.html). It would be easier to manage.

Comment: What have you tried so far and why has it not worked the way you wanted?